# Displaying dataTable with two nested lists

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I have a `List<List<String>>` and I am trying to display the data in a Primefaces/JSF `dataTable`. The list would look like this:

```
[["1_1", "1_2", "1_3"], ["2_1", "2_2", "2_3"], ["3_1", "3_2", "3_3"]]
```

The result table needs to look like this:

```
1_1 | 1_2 | 1_3
________________
2_1 | 2_2 | 2_3
________________
3_1 | 3_2 | 3_3
```

Probably I need something like an `ui:repeat` but unfortunately I can't find a solution. I am new to JSF and primefaces so I hope for your understanding.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try using https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml

Comment: Why are you using such an irregular data structure? It would be much easier if you convert your internal list to an Object and set that single list as value of `p:dataTable`.

Comment: Like `List<ObjectX>` which contains `x1, x2 & x3` properties to hold `"1_1", "1_2", "1_3"` values.

Comment: what about if your sublists contain different number of items?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, I used both html `<table>` and JSF `<h:dataTable>`.

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {
    private List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    public MyBean(){
        for(int i=1; i <=3; i++){
            List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int x=1; x <=3; x++){
                newList.add(i + "_" + x);
            }
            list.add(newList);
        }
    }
    public List<List<String>> getList(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

Using `<table>` and `<ui:repeat>`:

```
<table>
  <ui:repeat var="list" value="#{myBean.list}">
    <tr>
    <ui:repeat var="newlist" value="#{list}">
      <td>#{newlist}</td>
    </ui:repeat>
    </tr>
  </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

Using `<h:dataTable>`, each `List<String>` inside the List must have same sizes, if not you will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.list}" var="list">
  <h:column>
    #{list.get(0)}
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    #{list.get(1)}
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    #{list.get(2)}
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```